# Do I need RAID1 in a galera cluster?

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid, mariadb

I have a 3-node galera cluster that supposedly performs synchronous write replication across the entire cluster. I am trying to figure out if it is a good idea to use a software RAID1 3-HD on these boxes or if I can get away with software RAID0 3-HD on each box (and thus benefit from extra space :).

My understanding is the following:

- Because the application that stores data on these disks supposedly replicates writes synchronously, RAID1 should not provide more protection from disk failure.
- RAID0 should provide higher performance thanks to its stripes being spread across the disks.
- On the other hand, RAID1 might be able to provide better performance in case of disk failure because disk failure will result in the failure of a single disk rather than the entire node: I should still be able to export as part of the cluster the node that contains the failed HD until it has been replaced and the array has been rebuilt.
- I should be able to start with a RAID1 setup first and then switch to a RAID0 setup later if space becomes an issue which might be a good reason to start with RAID1 if there is really

Am I right on all counts ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it does depend on what the cluster is running. How important is IO performance to you? Is the data mission critical?

Personally with any production system, I tend to use RAID 1. Write performance will fall, but loss of data is never an option and RAID 0 is three times as likely to fail with three hard drives involved.